# Upload image to Google Drive for OCR

Tags: php, google-drive-api, ocr

I'm trying to upload an image to Google Drive for Optical Character Recognition (OCR). Here are my codes:

```
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

// Initialize Google Client
$client_email = 'xxxxxx@yyyyy.iam.gserviceaccount.com';
$private_key = file_get_contents('key.p12');
$scopes = array(
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
);
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    $client_email,
    $scopes,
    $private_key
);
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);
if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

// Initialize Google Drive service
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);

// Upload File
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName('Test Image for OCR');
$file->setDescription('Test Image for OCR');
$file->setMimeType('image/jpeg');
try {
  $data = file_get_contents($filename);
  $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
  ));
  var_dump($createdFile);
  // ===========
  // So, what's next?
  // ===========
} catch(Exception $e) {
  echo 'Error occurred: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

The above codes run without error, and the `$createdFile` is a valid resource in `Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile` object form.

Questions:

1. I guess the upload is successful, as the `create()` function does not return an error. However, I can't see the files got uploaded in my Google Drive. Shouldn't it be uploaded to Google Drive's root folder?
2. How can I perform OCR? I can read from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/create#parameters) that there is a parameter named `ocrLanguage`. Where should I put it and how do I obtain the result?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** The `var_dump()` results are as follow:

```
object(Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile)#18 (55) {
  ["collection_key":protected]=>
  string(6) "spaces"
  ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["appProperties"]=>
  NULL
  ["capabilitiesType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileCapabilities"
  ["capabilitiesDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["contentHintsType":protected]=>
  string(42) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileContentHints"
  ["contentHintsDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["createdTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["description"]=>
  NULL
  ["explicitlyTrashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["fileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["folderColorRgb"]=>
  NULL
  ["fullFileExtension"]=>
  NULL
  ["headRevisionId"]=>
  NULL
  ["iconLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["id"]=>
  string(28) "0B_XXXXX1yjq7dENaQWp4ckZoRk0"
  ["imageMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileImageMediaMetadata"
  ["imageMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["kind"]=>
  string(10) "drive#file"
  ["lastModifyingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["lastModifyingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["md5Checksum"]=>
  NULL
  ["mimeType"]=>
  string(10) "image/jpeg"
  ["modifiedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["modifiedTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["name"]=>
  string(18) "Test Image for OCR"
  ["originalFilename"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["ownersType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["ownersDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["parents"]=>
  NULL
  ["permissionsType":protected]=>
  string(31) "Google_Service_Drive_Permission"
  ["permissionsDataType":protected]=>
  string(5) "array"
  ["properties"]=>
  NULL
  ["quotaBytesUsed"]=>
  NULL
  ["shared"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharedWithMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["sharingUserType":protected]=>
  string(25) "Google_Service_Drive_User"
  ["sharingUserDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["size"]=>
  NULL
  ["spaces"]=>
  NULL
  ["starred"]=>
  NULL
  ["thumbnailLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["trashed"]=>
  NULL
  ["version"]=>
  NULL
  ["videoMediaMetadataType":protected]=>
  string(48) "Google_Service_Drive_DriveFileVideoMediaMetadata"
  ["videoMediaMetadataDataType":protected]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["viewedByMe"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewedByMeTime"]=>
  NULL
  ["viewersCanCopyContent"]=>
  NULL
  ["webContentLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["webViewLink"]=>
  NULL
  ["writersCanShare"]=>
  NULL
  ["modelData":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["processed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

The file can be obtained via `$service->files->get($file_id);`, but it's invisible in my Google Drive. The File Resource object returned does not contain anything useful either.

Comment: Your using a service account you uploaded the file to the service accounts google drive account you cant see that from the web version of google drive.   that is assuming I haven't missed the code where you upload it to a directory on your personal drive account.

Comment: Both correct. I'm using service account & trying to upload to personal account. So, how should I change my codes? which credentials should I use? I plan to use this code as a cron job / as an API that receives image file uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service account isn't you its more like a dummy user.  It has its own drive account.

If you want to upload to your personal account.  Take the service account email address and share it a directory in your personal drive account.   Just like you would any other user you wanted to share a directory or file with.

Then you need to figure out the directory id only way I have found to do that was to have the service account do a files.list to get a list of everything it now has access to.   Once you find the directory id or parent id 
you can change your code above to something like

```
'data' => $data,
'mimeType' => 'image/jpeg',
'parents'   => 'the directory id'
```

I think by the looks of your code you are using the V3 api I haven't had time to play with it.  `'parents'   => 'the directory id'`  <-- that is an educated guess.   If it doesn't work let me know and I will google around a bit to figure out how to pass parent to v3.

**Option nr 2:**

Another option would be for the service account to share its folder with you then you will have access to its drive account, and you will be able to see that folder in your web version of Drive.   Search around for permissions again I think you are using V3 I haven't looked at it yet.  Difference is where the data is stored and who the storage gets counted against.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think I will go for Option 1, which store the files in Service account. How about OCR part? Is there any way I can obtain OCR results, i.e. the recognized text?

Comment: I have never actually heard of OCR before I started Googling around the documentation for you.   It looks like it should automatically convert it to a google doc type.   V2 had an option for convert V3 doesn't appear to have that.  I may need to test this its a fun feature.

Comment: Thanks. Google just released another API for OCR, called Cloud Vision API, which is a non-free solution. I think the OCR ability of Drive API is reduced / removed due to this new API, but can't be sure as there is no documentation anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

I just found the way to OCR in V3.

1. Upload the image
2. Copy the image to a Google Document using mimeType **"application/vnd.google-apps.document"**
3. Export the Document as plain text using mimeType **"text/plain"**

P.S. Seems like step 2 won't work with "appDataFolder".

```
UserCredential credential = null;
try
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secret.json"), 
        new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile }, "user", CancellationToken.None);
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    Debug.Write("Credential failed, " + ex.Message);
}

// Create Drive API service.
var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = "TestApp",
});

// Create folder
var folderMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
folderMetadata.Name = "NewFolder";
folderMetadata.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
var request = service.Files.Create(folderMetadata);
request.Fields = "id";
var folder = request.Execute();
Debug.WriteLine("Folder ID: " + folder.Id);

// Upload the image file
var fileMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
fileMetadata.Name = inputFile.Name;
fileMetadata.Parents = new List<string> { folder.Id };
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload requestUpload;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(inputFile.Path, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    requestUpload = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
    requestUpload.Fields = "id";
    requestUpload.Upload();
}
var imgFile = requestUpload.ResponseBody;
Debug.WriteLine("File ID: " + imgFile.Id);

// Copy image and paste as document
var textMetadata = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File();
textMetadata.Name = inputFile.Name;
textMetadata.Parents = new List<string> { folderId };
textMetadata.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.document";
FilesResource.CopyRequest requestCopy = service.Files.Copy(textMetadata, imgFile.Id);
requestCopy.Fields = "id";
requestCopy.OcrLanguage = "zh";
var textFile = requestCopy.Execute();

// Now we export document as plain text
FilesResource.ExportRequest requestExport = service.Files.Export(textFile.Id, "text/plain");
string output = requestExport.Execute();
```

Comment: I'm working on a Win10 project so it's C#, hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your example, but I tagged the question for PHP, not C#.

Comment: I know, that's why I answered with the concept but you asked for my codes, just want to help.
Anyway, the concept is just the same as you do it with browser, check this out: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/google-drive-convert-image-to-text

Comment: Super helpful  @ramius

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a service account. If you want to upload to your own account, then you simply need to obtain an appropriate Access Token for your account. Using an intermediate account using shared folders is really ugly (imho).

Comment: I actually don't need to save the file at all. I just want to obtain OCR results.

Comment: I know what you want to do. Before Drive can OCR your image, you need to upload it. Before you can upload it, you need an access token for your account. It's all pretty simple once you get the hang of it.

Comment: I'm okay to obtain access token. However, I'm unable to obtain any OCR texts from API response (which field should I read?).

Comment: The text isn't in the response. The response is the meta data of the file you've just created. The response should contain an array of export links (v2) and I would suggest download from the text/plain link

Comment: This answer contains the steps necessary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481333/google-drive-sdk-uploading-image-ocr-download-result

Comment: but the link is for Android, ad that's for V2. The Drive SDK is now V3.

Comment: Neither matters. The steps are the same. If you read the code in the accepted answer, you'll see it's just grabbing the url from the export links. Also protocol v2 has not been deprecated, so you are free to use it. Once you've got your code working in v2, by all means look into what changes are required for v3 (although personally I'd wait a year or so)

Comment: Alright. I will try the V2 procedures. Ability of OCR of V3 seems to be moved to Cloud Vision API.

Comment: I don't see any mention of OCR being withdrawn in v3. On the contrary, the v3 migration doc at https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration says "OCR is enabled automatically for image imports".

Comment: Okay, will give it a try.