# ocr images from list of urls and store the results in spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, ocr

Hello I have a list of image URLs that contain numbers and I want to OCR them and store the results in google spreadsheet 
I've found these google scripts to ocr images

1- https://gist.github.com/tagplus5/07dde5ca61fe8f42045d

2- https://ctrlq.org/code/20128-extract-text-from-image-ocr

But I didn't know how to create a request variable so I've replaced request variable with URL variable like this:

```
function doGet(url) {
  if (url != undefined && url != "") {
    var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
    var resource = {
      title: imageBlob.getName(),
      mimeType: imageBlob.getContentType()
    };
    var options = {
      ocr: true
    };

    var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, imageBlob, options);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);
    var text = doc.getBody().getText().replace("\n", "");
    Drive.Files.remove(docFile.id);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(text);
  }
  else {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("request error");
  }
}
```

the problem is when I call the function like this doGet(B1) where B1 contain the url to the image in google spreadsheet to do the OCR and get the resulted text in the cell C1 it says Drive variable is undefined

Hope get answered soon

Comment: `Drive` is deprecated and became `DriveApp` and the posts you listed are out-of-date. Check this post instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12481333/google-drive-sdk-uploading-image-ocr-download-result

Comment: The link you've mentioned uses also the Drive function and I can't figure out how to modify the function doGet() so it gets the job done thanks

Comment: Oops you're right. I will search more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I modified your script and made a sheet to show an example. The sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11B0C3Y30VmYa5naN5mL1N2t5mlCIxHfmCcrjk95h36c/)(anyone can edit) and its script is below. Drive API(v2) of Advanced Drive Service should be enabled to run this script.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'RUN', functionName: 'doGet2'}
  ];

  ss.addMenu('OCR', menuItems);
}    


function doGet2() {
  var ROW_START = 3;
  var URL_COL = 1;
  var TEXT_COL = 2;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var urls = sheet.getRange(ROW_START,URL_COL, sheet.getLastRow()-ROW_START+1,1).getValues();
  var texts = [];
  for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
    var url = urls[i];
    if(url != undefined && url != "") {
      var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
      var resource = {
        title: imageBlob.getName(),
        mimeType: imageBlob.getContentType()
      };
      var options = {
        ocr: true
      };

      var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, imageBlob, options);
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);
      var text = doc.getBody().getText().replace("\n", "");

      texts.push([text]);
      Drive.Files.remove(docFile.id);
    }
    else {
      texts.push("request error");
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(ROW_START,TEXT_COL, urls.length,1).setValues(texts);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my Life

Answer (score 0):

The code is okay. V2 API is still alive. See [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive). All you need is to enable Advanced Drive Service. In the script editor, select **Resources > Advanced Google services** and turn on **Drive API** (only **v2** is selectable). Then your code actually works.

Comment: It seems that worked but it generated an error saying "Login Required" but I'm already logged in XD

Comment: I found this link but with no help
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing

it says in point 4-:Google displays a consent screen to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data.
but it didn't in in the sheet However it does show it in debug

Comment: Yes, you can't run the script at the sheet because it needs Drive API authorization. And seen from `doGet` and `return ContentService`, the script is for web apps, not for custom functions. Read [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). I suggest you list many URLs in the sheet, then run the script at the editor, or via some menu(look for `addMenu` function).

Comment: Either way, you should modify the input and output of the script.

Comment: Why and how because I need the function to ocr an image so in the input I give it is the url to the image and in the output I need the OCRed text I didn't see other way.I think,that I must add some code that authenticate and authorize the script to manipulate the file in google drive. and in the project properties it says 3 OAuth Scopes required by the script: googleapis.com/auth/documents googleapis.com/auth/drive googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request How do I provide them in the code.

this example is for blogger
https://gist.github.com/mhawksey/86287ea2fd247899d31a