# Google sheets OCR image at URL in Col1, output text in Col2?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

in a Google Sheet, I'm trying to use a function to OCR an image whose URL is in column A, and output the OCR text in column B. The code I'm attempting to use is from this thread:

[ocr images from list of urls and store the results in spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152604/ocr-images-from-list-of-urls-and-store-the-results-in-spreadsheet)

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var menuItems = [
    {name: 'RUN', functionName: 'doGet2'}
  ];

  ss.addMenu('OCR', menuItems);
}    


function doGet2() {
  var ROW_START = 3;
  var URL_COL = 1;
  var TEXT_COL = 2;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var urls = sheet.getRange(ROW_START,URL_COL, sheet.getLastRow()-ROW_START+1,1).getValues();
  var texts = [];
  for(var i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
    var url = urls[i];
    if(url != undefined && url != "") {
      var imageBlob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
      var resource = {
        title: imageBlob.getName(),
        mimeType: imageBlob.getContentType()
      };
      var options = {
        ocr: true
      };

      var docFile = Drive.Files.insert(resource, imageBlob, options);
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docFile.id);
      var text = doc.getBody().getText().replace("\n", "");

      texts.push([text]);
      Drive.Files.remove(docFile.id);
    }
    else {
      texts.push("request error");
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(ROW_START,TEXT_COL, urls.length,1).setValues(texts);
}
```

Here is the Google Sheet I'm testing with. Anyone can edit:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jhSmE295bTOzjoXmgcyymNi-6ylKg5PLEKktPZJTD1c/edit?usp=sharing

I think the original code is meant to pull from Google Drive. I don't need that, I just want to pull from a URL. Being able to use the function inside an arrayformula would be a plus.

Thanks!

Comment: When I saw your shared Spreadsheet, I noticed that you are trying to use `doGet2()` as a custom formula. In this case, Drive API, `DocumentApp.openById`, `setValues` and so on cannot be used because of the specification of the custom function. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) Also I think that your custom formula has already occurred the error. How about this?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, yes, I'm already certain that the current script doesn't work. I provided it mainly as a springboard for a working solution. Do you know what can be changed to adapt it to my needs?

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to achieve this using the custom function, unfortunately, it cannot be achieved because of the specification. So in this case, it is required to change the method for executing the script. But about this, I'm not sure about the goal you expect. I apologize for my poor English skill. By the way, about `yes, I'm already certain that the current script doesn't work.`, I think that the detail information about your issue should be included in your question.

Comment: @Tanaike I understand, the function can't be used as a formula. But I did get it to work as it was originally intended, so that's something. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hello @cyberspectre, would you mind posting the solution you found as an answer? So other's can benefit from it. Thanks!